# How do I create a variable in the second class to calculate the total price

Tags: java

While I was creating an application below, I want to know if there would be a way to calculate the total price by making a public void in the second class `AllFood`, instead of stating each prices in the class `Tester`. Since the price is different for every object, I want to know if I could put all of the prices in a one statement and calculate the total price so I could just put `food.getTotalPrice` in the print section.

The `Tester.java`:

```java
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    AllFood myobj = new AllFood();
    System.out.print("Enter number of hamburgers : ");
    int hamq = scan.nextInt();
    myobj.food("hamburger",9.0 , 33.0, 1.0);
    double price1 = hamq * 1.85;
    
    System.out.print("\n" + "Enter number of salads : ");
    int salq = scan.nextInt();
    myobj.food("salad", 1.0 , 11.0, 5.0);
    double price2 = salq*2.00;
    
    
    System.out.print("\n" + "Enter number of french fries : ");
    int ffq = scan.nextInt();
    myobj.food("french fry", 11.0 , 36.0, 4.0);
    double price3 = ffq * 1.30;
    
    
    System.out.print("\n" + "Enter number of sodas : ");
    int sodq = scan.nextInt();
    myobj.food("soda", 0.0 , 38.0, 0.0);
    double price4 =  sodq * 0.95;
    
    double totalPrice = price1 + price2 + price3 + price4;
    DecimalFormat money = new DecimalFormat("$##.##");
    System.out.print("\n" + "Your order comes to : " + money.format(totalPrice));

   }
}
```

The `AllFood.java`:

```java
public class AllFood {
    
    private String food;
    private double price, total, quantity, fat, carbs, fiber;
    
    public AllFood() {
        food ="";
    quantity = 0;
    fat=0;
    carbs=0;
    fiber =0;
    price=0;
    }
    
    public AllFood(String fo, double q, double f, double c, double fi, double p) {
    food=fo;
    quantity = q;
    fat= f;
    carbs = c;
    fiber = fi;
    price = p;
    
    }

    public void food(String fo, double f,double c, double fi) {
    System.out.println("Each " + fo + " has " + f + "gs of fat, "+ c + "gs of carbs, and " + fi + "gs  of fiber.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont tho=ink below lines are serving any purpose
    
    myobj.food("hamburger",9.0 , 33.0, 1.0);
    myobj.food("french fry", 11.0 , 36.0, 4.0);

You can make use of Factory design pattern for such refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to get the total price of the food from `AllFood` you need to store the list of foods. This means having another class Food to store the single foods objects:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        AllFood myobj = new AllFood();
        System.out.print("Enter number of hamburgers : ");
        int hamq = scan.nextInt();
        double price1 = hamq * 1.85;
        Food hamburger = new Food("hamburger",price1,hamq,9.0 , 33.0, 1.0);
        System.out.print(hamburger.toString());
        myobj.addFood(hamburger);
        
        System.out.print("\n" + "Enter number of salads : ");
        int salq = scan.nextInt();
        double price2 = salq*2.00;
        Food salad = new Food("salad",price2,salq,1.0 , 11.0, 5.0);
        System.out.print(salad.toString());
        myobj.addFood(salad);
        
        
        System.out.print("\n" + "Enter number of french fries : ");
        int ffq = scan.nextInt();
        double price3 = ffq * 1.30;
        Food frenchFry = new Food("french fry",price3,ffq,11.0 , 36.0, 4.0);
        System.out.print(frenchFry.toString());
        myobj.addFood(frenchFry);
        
        System.out.print("\n" + "Enter number of sodas : ");
        int sodq = scan.nextInt();
        double price4 =  sodq * 0.95;
        Food soda = new Food("soda",price4,sodq,11.0 , 36.0, 4.0);
        System.out.print(soda.toString());
        myobj.addFood(soda);
        
        DecimalFormat money = new DecimalFormat("$##.##");
        System.out.print("\n" + "Your order comes to : " + money.format(myobj.getTotalPrice()));
    }
}
```

This is the class `AllFoods`:

```
public class AllFood {
    private List<Food> foods;

    public AllFood() {
        this.foods=new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    public void addFood(Food food) {
        this.foods.add(food);
    }

    
    public double getTotalPrice() {
        double price = 0;
        for(Food food:foods) {
            price += food.getPrice();
        }
        return price;
    }
}
```

And finally the class `Food`:

```
public class Food {
    private String name;
    private double price, quantity, fat, carbs, fiber;
    
    public Food(String name, double price, double quantity, double fat, double carbs, double fiber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.fat = fat;
        this.carbs = carbs;
        this.fiber = fiber;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Each " + name + " has " + fat + "gs of fat, " + carbs + "gs of carbs, and " + fiber + "gs  of fiber.";
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```